# Firebird 1.5 : Duplicate columns in a table

Tags: firebird, firebird1.5

I noticed that Firebird creates duplicate columns for a single table, thus incorrect indices are being used in the query which cause query to be slow. Please example below.

I have 2 tables with the same columns and indices, but when checking the table structure, one table shows duplicate columns

```
Table A : Name VARCHAR(30)
          Age  INTEGER
          BIRTH_DATE TIMESTAMP

          Indices : Name, Birth_date (Asc), Birth_date(Desc)

Table B : Name VARCHAR(30)
          Age  INTEGER
          BIRTH_DATE TIMESTAMP   
          Name VARCHAR(30)
          Age  INTEGER
          BIRTH_DATE TIMESTAMP   

          Indices : Name, Birth_date (Asc), Birth_date(Desc)
```

When joining the table with Table C and order by Birth_date, Table A is using the Birth_date index Ordered, but Table B is not.

Please help! what is the cause behind this? Thank you.

Comment: What is the actual DDL of the table? It should not be possible to create two columns with the same name (and case).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, yup, it is not possible create the two columns with the same name in one table, but you could create same columns in different tables, the problem is if two tables with the same columns, one of them will have duplicate columns when I view the DDL in squirrel (IDE for Firebird).

Comment: That could also be a bug in the metadata query in Jaybird, could you create a ticket on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC describing the problem, reproduction steps, actual DDL and a copy (or backup) of the database?

Answer (score 1):

I just had a problem where a duplicate column had been allowed to be created. This request

```
SELECT a.RDB$FIELD_NAME
FROM RDB$RELATION_FIELDS a
WHERE a.RDB$FIELD_NAME like '%COLUMN_NAME%'
```

was showing two COLUMN_NAME lines. By copy pasting the fields elsewhere it became apparent that one column had trailing whitespace, while the other had a carriage return + line feed (CRLF) and then trailing whitespace.

The FlameRobin wizard was used to create the column. My take on it is a copy-paste was used and a CRLF was inserted. Excel and other softwares can do that to you. FlameRobin, FlameRobin's driver and FireBird should each guard against that, though.

We dropped the offending column by crafting some DDL which had the offending CRLF in the column name.